# How would you go about disabling a button as long as 2 text fields are empty in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a view controller that controls 2 text fields and an array that displays in a table. How would I go about keeping a button disabled until the 2 fields have at least one character and the array is not empty. I am thinking about using cocoa bindings, however I can't seem to figure out a solution.

Currently my button is binded to

```
BOOL buttonIsEnabled;
```

I use that in a notification function in order to keep the button disabled, except the button will only reenable if I call that notification function.

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange
```

This means if i make a change in an array, the button wont reenable until I re-enter text. I can't seem to figure out an alternative solution. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution:

- bind the two text fields two two strings (say `text1` and `text2`)
- in the text field bindings check *Continuously Updates Value*

Add this code:

```
- (BOOL)buttonIsEnabled {

    return (self.text1.length>0 && self.text2.length>0);
}
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingButtonIsEnabled {

    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text1",@"text2",nil];
}
```

- Lastly bind the buttons enabled binding to `buttonIsEnabled`.

Because of the *Continuously Updates Value* text1 or text2 will change whenever characters are added to or removed from the text fields.

And the `+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingButtonIsEnabled` method will cause a Key-Value change notification to be posted for `buttonIsEnabled` whenever `text1` or `text2` change.

Comment: Hello, This seems to be the solution I am looking for. Just struggling with app crashing at start now. You missed the array part though, continuous updates have to also check and array size. I guess I have to bind the array to an array controller too?

Comment: The array controller already takes care of updating your array. So just add `@"myArrayName"` to the set, and check the arrays `count` property in the `buttonIsEnabled` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom cell, give outlets to your 2 textfields and button.

Now on cell for row at index path after filling the textfields text values, put a condition checking the length of the textfields. If length is greater than 0 you can enable the button or keep it disable.

Along with this you need to put same code in delegate method (textFieldDidChange) of textfield. So that when ever new text is entered the button gets enable or disabled.